# Overlapping issue of fragments in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-bottomnav

I have a bottom navigation menu in my app, on **"Create"** menu. I am displaying the fragment page. It's working totally fine but when I click on my next menu which is **"Fav", "saved", "hidden" and "more"**. The specified activity is opened with the fragment of **"create"** menu overlapped on it. Any help is appreciated

```java
private void selectTab(int pos, int mainMode) {
    MenuItem navItem = null;
    Fragment selectedFragment=null;
    switch (mainMode) {
        case 0:
            selectedFragment=new FirebaseFragment();
            //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirebaseFragment.class);
            //startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 1:
            navItem =  _bottomNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_mode_favs);
            break;
        case 2:
            navItem = _bottomNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_mode_saved);
            break;
        case 3:
            navItem =  _bottomNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_mode_hidden);
            break;
        case 4:
            navItem =  _bottomNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_more);
            break;
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer,selectedFragment).commit();

    if (navItem != null) {
        navItem.setChecked(true);
        onNavigationItemSelected(navItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your activity's whole code ?

Comment: hi nice umang..i tried posting whole code but it exceeded the characters limit

Comment: where you commit your fragment when your mainMode is not 0 i means other then 0?

Comment: when mainmode is 0

Comment: `onNavigationItemSelected` is not added to this question, so we have no idea.